# What is the right UI pattern for an optional date?

Tags: android

I am using a DialogFragment to show a DatePicker to choose a date. The point is that such date could be optional, so somewhere i should display a checkbox asking to use the date or not. So how would you do such an UI ?.

So far i tried adding a checkbox on the same DialogFragment but i believe the interaction wont be very intuitive because if you choose the checkbox "no date" i would have to block or disable the datepicker but i wasn't able to do that and even if i do i am not sure if it is the best approach.

Have you seen any application solving a problem like this and how does it solve it ?

Comment: I would put the checkbox at where you put your button, which start DatePickerDialogFragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I solved it in my app: make it clear on the button that launches the DialogFragment that a date is optional.

[image: no date chosen]

After a date is chosen, add the option to remove it. Clicking on the "x" restores the button to look like above.

[image]